# How do I get server date using Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I want to get the server date using my linq to sql, so I add a partial class of DataContext class and add a method to retrieve the date:

```
Partial Public Class DBDataContext
    <Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name:="GetDate", IsComposable:=true)> _
    Public Function GetSystemDate() As DateTime
        Dim mi As MethodInfo = TryCast(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()  ,  MethodInfo)
        Return CType(Me.ExecuteMethodCall(Me, mi, New Object()).ReturnValue, DateTime ) 'exception here
    End Function
End Class
```

but I'm getting this exception that I could understand:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

where did I go wrong?

Comment: ExecuteMethodCall method will take third parmater as Array

Type: System.Object()
The array of parameters to be passed to the command. 


[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb493883.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why but adding braces solved the problem.

```
Partial Public Class DBDataContext
    <Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name:="GetDate", IsComposable:=true)> _
    Public Function GetSystemDate() As DateTime
        Dim mi As MethodInfo = TryCast(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()  ,  MethodInfo)
        Return CType(Me.ExecuteMethodCall(Me, mi, New Object(){}).ReturnValue, DateTime ) 'exception here
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: ExecuteMethodCall method will take third parmater as Array

Type: System.Object()
The array of parameters to be passed to the command.   

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb493883.aspx)